# What is it called when a website URL replaces WWW with something else, and what purpose does it serve?

Tags: html, websites

What is it called when a website has another word in place of where `www` usually goes? For example, `images.google.com` vs `google.com/images`. I know the latter is a file on the server that the browser downloads, but what exactly is the purpose of the former? It would be helpful to know what this is called.

Comment: `google.com/images` is a **sub-directory** and not a **file**

Comment: @Alok regarding google it is no "directory" ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is is called a subdomain.

Subdomains can be routed via the cname entry to a different server so that when the user types in `foo.bar.com`, the nameserver for `bar.com` is examined, which reveals the IP address for the `foo` subdomain.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I can find more information by myself now. It was hard to describe in a Google query without knowing the name haha. I'll mark you as the right answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: `foo` is a host. `bar` is a subdomain. (`com` is also technically speaking a subdomain of the root domain `.`.)

Comment: @Carpetfizz - For what it's worth, `www` is also a subdomain, just one that's *by convention* used for the main webserver.

Answer (score 5):

Back before the world wide web was invented, servers used the convention of using different host names to access different services. So, for example, if "Example Corporation" had a public server, it was named "example.com". If they provided public [ftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) access, it would be accessible through the hostname "ftp.example.com". The "ftp" part identified an actual server machine on the subdomain "example.com".

Likewise, if "example.com" provided a public [smtp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp) server, it would be "smtp.example.com". If they provided a [gopher server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_%28protocol%29), it would be "gopher.example.com". When web servers were invented, pretty much everyone stuck to this convention and named their websites with "www" (eg: www.example.com).

*This is simply a convention*. Once websites started to proliferate, sites started using their corporate hostname as the main website to make it easier for people to get to the website, so instead of "www.example.com", the simpler "example.com" would be routed to the web server. As traffic increased, they could have multiple servers, with a load balancer sitting between "example.com" and the various servers that power it.

Answer (score 4):

As Keldon said, subdomain is the term you are looking for.

The purpose is generally/originally was to allow someone to control their own mappings of the names to various IP addresses / servers by providing a domain name server themselves rather than registering a bunch of separate domains.

These days there are a fair number of people that use subdomains on the same IP address to do things with cookie/script scope, or to allow their networking hardware to decide where to route the traffic.

For example, resources embedded withing my pages like photos might be referred to at a subdomain like http://staticresource.xyzcompany.com and in my load balancer I could route those through a cache appliance even though they live on the main http://xyzcomapny.com domain.  This lowers the load on my actual web server and speeds up page loads to the clients without be having to do separate deploys and maintain separate actual servers.

I can also use it as it was originally used and assign a separate subdomain to a separate  IP address on a separate server to http://scaryadmintools.xyzcompany.com then put different rules and settings on that server to increase security while isolating that overhead from the general marketing site at the main domain.

Comment: Good point.  To add to your network routing rules, I believe that IE also has the ability to say certain *sites* are whitelisted, but not certain *paths* on a site.

Comment: Most browsers can do that with certificate scopes and such...  There are a lot of reasons that you can do this, these are just the ones that happen the most and are explainable.  Tokenized subdomains or CDN internals with shortest response DNS are another good use here, but explaining the how of that gets confusing to many people in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

This is usuall accomplished by a [url redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection). No page is ever downloaded. Your browser requests the /images resource from the web server (sitting at google.com). The webserver responds saying "this is not the resource you're looking for" and points your browser to images.google.com (like the Bugs Bunny cartoon where Elmer Fudd asks "the park ranger" which way the wascally wabbit went and "the park ranger" says he went thataway).

Your browser then goes to images.google.com and says gimme what you got (or "get /"). The server responds with the appropriate resource.

Comment: I like this answer for the fact you used Bugs Bunny and Elmer Fudd to to explain redirections and browser requests! ;)

Comment: I try not to take myself too seriously :)

Answer (score 2):

The host name `www` is a host name.  It makes it convenient for people to know where to go for a given service, and as a convention, just entering the domain name (for example `google`) in many browsers, the browser will go to `www.domain.com`.

However, this points to a host (load balanced it may be), but it points to one server (-ish, yes, there's dns round robin too).  This can cause significant traffic to one server, which can be a bad thing.

It is a standard approach to split the dynamic content and static content into two parts and host the static content on a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (Content Delivery Network).  This requires pointing dns to a different server.  As such, the host name for the dynamic content cannot be the same as the static content.